# Installed package xlsx doesn't work in R

Tags: r

I've been trying to install the package "xlsx" in R. First time that I tried to do so, R gave me the error:

```
package ‘xlsx’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘xlsx’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)
```

After that, I tried to install the package using the command `install.packages("xlsx",type="source")`. Then it seemed like the package had been installed successfully:

```
 * installing *source* package 'xlsx' ...
    ** package 'xlsx' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** R
    ** inst
    ** preparing package for lazy loading
    ** help
    *** installing help indices
    ** building package indices
    ** installing vignettes
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded
    *** arch - i386
    *** arch - x64
    * DONE (xlsx)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\zahra\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpszYeze\downloaded_packages’
```

But still when I try to execute `read.xlsx` command, R gives me the error:

```
Error: could not find function "read.xlsx"
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone tells me what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do the `library(xlsx)` command before using the `read.xlsx` function?

Comment: there is a new library, readxl, which has no external dependencies.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing Step 3 of the accepted answer in my suggested dupe: load the package with `library()` or `require()`.

Comment: This package uses Java. Do you have any trouble with `require(rJava)`?

Comment: @JohnPaul Yeah...Sounds like that was the problem. Thanks.